# Unable to move a directory from one location to another without an exception error

Tags: c#, .net

I am having a strange problem trying to move a folder from the C:\Program Files\mycompany\myapp to the users appData folder.  All the folder paths appear to be fine (as shown in the messagebox.show), but the exception error still occurs and indicates there is an issue with the path.

The code is as follows:

Move VS Media Folder from C:\Program Files\mycompany\myapp\VS Media Application folder to userPath

```
string userPath = C:\Users\VS-VM\AppData\Local\mycompany\VS Media\        
string vsMediaFolder = Path.GetDirectoryName(Context.Parameters["AssemblyPath"].ToString()) + @"\VS Media\";
string vsMediaPath = UserPath + @"VS Media\";

    MessageBox.Show("Source VS Media Folder " + vsMediaFolder +  " target VS MediaPath " + vsMediaPath);  //all these paths are correct as expected

        try
        {
            if (Directory.Exists(vsMediaPath))
            {
                // MessageBox.Show("VS Media exists - deleting");
                Directory.Delete(vsMediaPath, true);
            }


              Directory.Move(vsMediaFolder, vsMediaPath); 

        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            MessageBox.Show (e.ToString());
            MessageBox.Show("Unable to move " + vsMediaFolder + " to Destination " + vsMediaPath  ); 
         }
```

This gives an exception error about the path not being full - yet if I use just use VsMediaPath = userPath (without the @"VS media), it copies the files from source vsMediaFolder directly into the userPath folder without error.

This shows the correct path for both source and destination.

I also tried to do a file copy instead of the move and also get errors.
It creates the right folders in the userPath, but as soon as it tries to copy the files I get
an exception error (below) about the path again.

```
            Directory.CreateDirectory(vsMediaPath);
            string[] files = Directory.GetFiles(vsMediaFolder);
            for (int i = 0; i < files.Length; i++)
                File.Copy(vsMediaFolder + files[i], vsMediaPath + files[i]);
            Directory.Delete(vsMediaFolder);
```

System.NotSupportedException: The given path's format is not supported.

at System.Security.Util.StringExpressionSet.CanonicalizePath(String path, Boolean needFullPath)

at System.Security.Util.StringExpressionSet.CreateListFromExpressions(String[] str, Boolean needFullPath)

at System.Security.Permissions.FileIOPermission.AddPathList(FileIOPermissionAccess access, AccessControlActions control, String[] pathListOrig, Boolean checkForDuplicates, Boolean needFullPath, Boolean copyPathList)

at System.Security.Permissions.FileIOPermission.AddPathList(FileIOPermissionAccess access, String[] pathListOrig, Boolean checkForDuplicates, Boolean needFullPath, Boolean copyPathList)

at System.Security.Permissions.FileIOPermission..ctor(FileIOPermissionAccess access, String[] pathList, Boolean checkForDuplicates, Boolean needFullPath)

at System.IO.File.InternalCopy(String sourceFileName, String destFileName, Boolean overwrite)

Then it verifies the paths are still correct after the exception.
Unable to move C:\Program Files\mycompany\myApp\VS Media\ to Destination C:\Users\VS-VM\AppData\Local\mycompany\VS Media\

So I am not sure what is wrong?

Comment: can you provide `vsMediaPath` value?

Comment: `Directory.GetFiles` return Full path to files, not only file name

Comment: The string in your first line of code is not double quoted. I suppose that's not the way it actually looks in your program...

Comment: I did not copy it correctly, it does have quotes in the original code.

Answer (score 0):

in msdn [Directory.GetFiles](http://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/07wt70x2%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)

> Returns the names of files (**including their paths**) in the specified directory.

so instead this

```
File.Copy(vsMediaFolder + files[i], vsMediaPath + files[i]);
```

you must use

```
File.Copy(files[i], vsMediaPath + Path.GetFileName(files[i]));
```

Comment: Yes. That solved the issue. Thank You.  I had seen this code in another posting, and did not realize that the full pathname was included in the filename (which I should have known).